# Create Source, Target and sum of counts between a group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks something as follows:

| id | product | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | month 0 |
| 1 | A | month 1 |
| 1 | B | month 2 |
| 2 | A | month 0 |
| 2 | A | month 1 |
| 2 | A | month 2 |
| 2 | D | month 3 |

Desired output

| source | target | product | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| month 0 | month 1 | A | 2 |
| month 0 | month 1 | B | 0 |
| month 1 | month 2 | A | 1 |
| month 1 | month 2 | B | 1 |
| month 2 | month 3 | D | 1 |

The goal is to count the total ids going from month to month and grouping by product.
I'm just totally stuck on how to first split the column date as source and target. Maybe once I do that I can just do something like:

```
df %>% group(product,source,target) %>% mutate(length(unique(id))
```

Not completely sure, any help would be great.

Comment: I'm unclear about what specific rules get from your input to your output. It seems like in some cases you need to have both months present, in other cases just the 2nd month.

Comment: Is target simply one more than source?  It's probably better to save an integer (or date) rather than a string "month x".

Comment: I prefer having the months as an integer. The months column could be anything. It could have even been cars, buses, etc. I want to show a flow from one node to another. This is mainly for Sankey. So I want unique counts between each flow. Does that make sense. I'm sorry I didn't show a better scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try: Not the expected output because as @Jon Spring noted it is not fully clear:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr) # parse_number
df %>% 
  mutate(date = parse_number(date)) %>% 
  group_by(id, product) %>% 
  add_count(name="sum") %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(sum>1, lead(date), date-1)) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  mutate(source = ifelse(date < x, date, x), 
         target = ifelse(date > x, date, x), .keep="unused") %>% 
  mutate(across(c(source, target), ~paste("month", .)))
```

```
     id product   sum source  target 
  <int> <chr>   <int> <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 A           2 month 0 month 1
2     1 B           1 month 1 month 2
3     2 A           3 month 0 month 1
4     2 A           3 month 1 month 2
5     2 D           1 month 2 month 3
```

Comment: Do you know why the sum is showing up as 3 for line 3, when there are only 2 unique ids?

Comment: because add_count gives a new column and does not summarise. add_count is like mutate(xx = count(yyy)), whereas count summarizes the group.

Comment: z <- df %>% 
  mutate(date = parse_number(date)) %>% 
  group_by(id, product) %>% 
  add_count(name="sum") %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(sum>1, lead(date), date-1)) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  mutate(source = ifelse(date < x, date, x), 
         target = ifelse(date > x, date, x), .keep="unused") %>% 
  mutate(across(c(source, target), ~paste("month", .))) 

x <- z %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(product,source,target) %>% mutate(total = length(unique(id))) %>% select(product,source,target,total)  

when I do that ^ I don't get the row: B month 0 month 1  0 ( <- total)
any ideas? so close!